# Dijkstra shortest path on multiple unweighted graphs?

Tags: c++, graph-algorithm, dijkstra

I'm trying to figure out how to implement djiktra algorithm to find the shortest path between **2 unweighted graphs.** The suggestion I got was to use 2 graphs one for the red color and one for the blue color.**The cost is always 1 to travel** but to access a red square while being blue you need to **pay 2 to switch graph**.

**I'm mostly looking for suggestions and references has anyone done something similar ???**

[image]

Comment: You should add some of your code, what have you tried so far?

Comment: you can still model that as one graph. red-red edges have weight 1 and red-blue edges have weight 3 (1 for normal travel , plus 2 for switching colors)

Comment: This is **not** an unweighted graph. The cost is either 1 or 2 (or is it 1 or 3 the question does not make it clear). This should be a standard Dijkstra algorithm that applies this cost value.

Comment: _The suggestion I got was to use 2 graphs _ I recommend ignoring this suggestion. It should be modeled as one weighted graph.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new weighted graph based on the original graph where a blue -> red path costs 3 instead of 1, then run Dijkstra on that.

Edit: it's probably not necessary to actually create the new graph, you can get the weights directly from the original graph, but creating the new graph first is probably easier to follow at first.

The top corner would look like this:

```
A ← 3 → B ← 1 → C ← 1 → D ...
↑       ↑       ↑
1       1       3  
↓       ↓       ↓
E ← 3 → F ← 3 → G...
```

Comment: The problem is that if I change color to blue by paying 2 i should not have to continue to pay 3 each time i walk on a blue tile

Comment: yes, only adjust the cost for the edges that change color

Comment: so i need to consistently change the graph weight on each color change ?

Comment: I've added a sample for the top-left corner of your original graph, hope that makes it clearer

Comment: Ok so what your saying is that only if a red and blue are connected together the cost should be 3 otherwise it's 1

Comment: @BrokenStarz111, it is implicit in the graphs being two rather than a single one that there are (initially) no edges connecting nodes belonging to different graphs.  What you are doing is combining the two into one by adding such edges, with appropriate weight, wherever appropriate.  The weights of the original edges do not change.

Comment: Incidentally, it is unclear to me from the problem description whether the weights of the added edges should be 3 (2 to change color plus one to take a step) or 2 (to take a step from one color to the other).

Answer (score 2):

This is simply standard Dijkstra.

This is not an unweighted graph, you have a cost of moving from one vertex to another. There is just an extra rule in the swapping from one color to another bares an additional cost.

All you need is a function to calculate the cost between two vertexes that simply looks at the color of each vertex and increases the cost appropriately. See: `int getCost(Graph const& graph, Point src, Point dst)` below.

Other than that it is a standard algorithym you should be applying.

---

```
// Not pure C++
// But left enough work that you have to make an effort
// to complete this.

enum Color { Red, Blue};
using Graph = std::vector_like<std::vector_like<Color>>;
using Point = std::pair<int, int>;

int getCost(Graph const& graph, Point src, Point dst)
{
    // Assumes: src and dst are 1 point away from each other.
    //          This assumes that work is done via
    //          getListOfPointsReachable() which only gets nodes
    //          nodes that are adjecent.
    //          
    // Standard movement cost.
    int cost = 1;

    // Add a cost if switching between blue red.
    if (graph[src] !=  graph[dst]) {
        cost += 2;
    }
    return cost;
}

std::list<Point> getListOfPointsReachable(Graph const& graph, Point src)
{
    // Get a list of points that can be accessed by src.
    // All points that are next to the current and return as a list.
    // Check if they are out of bounds.
}

void Dijkstra(Graph const& graph, Point start, Point end)
{
    std::set<Point>  visited;

    // Boundary:  int   => Cost
    //            Point => Point cost applies to.
    // Using tuple as it already has the comparison operator defined.
    using Boundary = std::tuple<int, Point>;
    std:: priority_queue<Boundary>   boundary;

    // Set up the boundary list with a start.
    boundary.emplace(0, start);

    while (!boundary.empty())
    {
        Boundary next = boundry.top();
        boundary.pop();

        int      cost = std::get<0>(next);
        Point    nextP = std::get<1>(next);

        if (nextP == end)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Found route to end: Cheapest Route is: " + cost);
        }
        if (visited.find(nextP) != std::end(visited))
        {
            // we already did this node.
            continue;
        }
        visited.insert(nextP);

        std::list<Point> dests = getListOfPointsReachable(graph, nextP);
        for (auto const& dest: dests)
        {
            int extraCost = getCost(graph, nextP, dest);
            boundary.emplace(extraCost + cost, dest);
        }
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("No Route from Start to End");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To create the graph, use this psuedo code to add edges between nodes

```
AddEdge( n1, n2 )
SET cost = 1
IF n1color != n2color
   SET cost = 3;
graph.AddEdge( n1, n2, cost );
RUN Dijsktra on graph
```